# Linux command populate file from php script output

Tags: php, linux, file, command-line, touch

I have a PHP script which generates some complex XML output. The XML is currently being output as a webpage but instead of a webpage I need it as a physical file on my server.

So, I wonder if there is a way to pipe the output of my PHP script into the Linux touch command so that my PHP output populates, or overrides, a file on my server?

I am currently trying the following code without success:

```
touch test | php xml_reports.php
```

Comment: php xml_reports.php > test

Answer (score 2):

You can actually run PHP from the command line.

```
php filename.php
```

So if your php file consisted of:

```
<?php
    echo "Hello World";
?>
```

The output would be "Hello World" (without the quotes) in your terminal. So if you were writing an application in PHP, try and think about how you would approach it without the browser rendering your output.  I hope that helps.

[edit]
You might also want to look into shell_exec. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand your question correctly, here is a solution.  In this case however, rather than piping the PHP output, the PHP code itself outputs a copy of the file on the server.  I'm not sure how vital it is that this is done through a linux pipe.  Also note that this solution is copied from http://forums.codewalkers.com/showpost.php?p=40350&postcount=3.

> 1) at the very start of your script put this line :
>
> ```
> ob_start();
> ```
>
> 2) at the very end of your script, put this:
>
> ```
> $page = ob_get_contents();
> ob_end_flush();
> $fp = fopen("output.html","w");
> fwrite($fp,$page);
> fclose($fp);
> ```
>
> And, bam, you should have the whole page in a file called output.html.
>   Now, one thing you need to be sure of is that the webserver server can
>   write the file output.html. That means you need to make sure the
>   webserver has the permissions to write in whatever directory you plan
>   to store that file in.
>
> How does it work? Basically, it just buffers all output from your
>   script. Then, you store that buffer into a string. Then you send the
>   buffer to the browser. Then you store that string in a file...

Comment: I have tried numerous approaches to create the output from my PHP script but I get permission denied errors. Hence, I decided to deal with the file creation from the server commandline. However, I will try your approach

Comment: Hi Michael, as I suspected, I get a permission denied error when I try your approach. I'm sure your suggestion has merit but trying it in a Drupal module on a Linux server does not allow it to work unhindered

Comment: That's unfortunate - are you able to get Alex's approach above to work?  That would be my next suggestion.